# Browser based PC benchmarking?

Tags: webapp-rec

It's often difficult to know the true performance of a computer when you see it at a store. While the store may allow you to use the browser, they usually don't allow you to install custom software, such as for benchmarking.

For that reason, I am looking for a webapp which can perform benchmark tests on a PC by using something like JavaScript, Flash or even Java.

Ideally, the solution should test every aspect of the PC such as the processor, hard-drive, ram, and even graphics.

I've seen [Peacekeeper](http://clients.futuremark.com/peacekeeper/browserStatistics.action), but it seems like it's intended more for testing browsers against each other rather than testing PC's against each other.

Answer (score 0):

Not *exactly* what you're looking for but the one website I know that getting close :

[Can You Run It?](http://cyri.systemrequirementslab.com/CYRI/)

> This site provides a One-Click
>   solution that looks at your computer's
>   hardware and system software to
>   determine whether or not your current
>   system can run a product.

The analysis results you get take into account CPU, ram, OS, Video card and Sound card : eg. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1026715/stackexchange/labanalysi.JPG